# Db2 Z/OS Table Size

Tags: sql, zos, db2-zos

Is there a way to get table or tablespace size accurately via SQL for Db2 Z/OS?
From whatever I can find, there has been information with regards to Db2 LUW but not for z/OS.

I found a [article](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/how-calculate-uncompressed-db2-zos-table-sizes-db2-analytics-accelerator) for z/OS, which as I understand cannot be done from SQL side(using Dbeaver or TOAD, etc) and requires going on the mainframe side as well.

Would be great to get some assistance here.

Comment: Why do you need to know the table size?

Comment: @cschneid Not sure how to answer this question. Need to know this for various purposes, as to which table is the biggest, which requires to moved to a different storage, maintenance activities, etc.
Are you saying table size is something not a practice in z/OS?

Comment: These are all DBA tasks.  I'm saying if you aren't the DBA then this isn't your problem, and if you are the DBA then I'd recommend you refer to [the IBM documentation](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2-for-zos/12?topic=recovery-backing-up-recovering-your-data) before SO.

Answer (score 0):

You may take a Look at SYSIBM.SYSTABLESPACE.
If Statistics are accurate following Columns will help you:
PGSIZE (SMALLINT Size of one Page in KB)
NACTIVEF (FLOAT Number of active Pages)
STATSTIME (Timestamp Time of RUNSTATS Util)